# not able to access the results of the ng-repeat angularjs to use in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Sorry, i'am a new programmer.
This is my html script

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText"><a onclick="eraseText('{{friend.id_app}}')"  href="#"><i class="{{friend.icon}}" style=" padding:2px; color:{{friend.warna}}';"></i>{{friend.prog_name}}</a></li>
```

And This my js

```
function eraseText(id_app1) {
alert(id_app1);
document.getElementById("search-ac").style.display = "none";
var url = 'description_app.php';
var id_app = id_app1;
    $.post(url, {id_app: id_app} ,function(data) {
      $(".modal-body").html(data).show();
});}
```

And I get this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80eqb.jpg)

Comment: Use `ng-click="eraseText(friend.id_app)"` and define `eraseText` in `$scope` instead.

Comment: what is  searchText in  filter:searchText  is it controller variable ? do you get any console error ?

Comment: I tried it and not work

Comment: This is my searchText  : <input id="search" type="search" name="search" ng-model="searchText"/>

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ng-click` and `ng-href` instead of `onclick` and `href` when you are working with ***AngularJS***.

Your code should look like this.

```
<li ng-repeat = "friend in friends | filter:searchText">
    <a ng-click = "eraseText('{{friend.id_app}}')" ng-href = "<HTTP_LINK>">
        <i class = "{{friend.icon}}" style = " padding:2px; color:{{friend.warna}}';">
        </i>
        {{friend.prog_name}}
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the parameter to the function `eraseText()` as a string, that's why you are getting this output. Also, use the angular event `ng-click`. Change your code to from  -

```
onclick="eraseText('{{friend.id_app}}')"
```

to

```
 ng-click="eraseText(friend.id_app)"
```